# How to filter an array of objects using multiple conditions in JSONPATH?

Tags: jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am using jsonpath library (https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) in Go, and I need to process a JSON object and filter from an array of objects, the objects which match any of the multiple criteria (OR conditions). I have been unsuccessful in getting the filter to work correctly and hoping that someone can help me in the right direction. I am providing a simplified example below.

Let us assume I have the following JSON Object.

```json
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName" : "doe",
  "age"      : 26,
  "address"  : {
    "streetAddress": "naist street",
    "city"         : "Nara",
    "postalCode"   : "630-0192"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type"  : "iPhone",
      "number": "123-4567-8888"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "home",
      "number": "123-4567-8910"
    },
    {
      "type"  : "mobile",
      "number": "123-4567-1233"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like filter all phone numbers (phoneNumbers) which are of type "home" or "iPhone". I have used the following expression, but it results in an empty array:

`$.phoneNumbers[?(@.type=='home' || @.type == 'iPhone')]`

Please see this JSONPath expression tester below. I have saved the JSON here, but it doesn't keep the JSONPath expression, and it will need to be pasted manually.
[JSONPath Expression Tester](https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/?data=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%22firstName%22%3A%20%22John%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22lastName%22%20%3A%20%22doe%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22age%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%2026%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22address%22%20%20%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22streetAddress%22%3A%20%22naist%20street%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22city%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%22Nara%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22postalCode%22%20%20%20%3A%20%22630-0192%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%22phoneNumbers%22%3A%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%20%3A%20%22iPhone%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22number%22%3A%20%220123-4567-8888%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%20%20%3A%20%22home%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%22number%22%3A%20%220123-4567-8910%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%5D%0D%0A%7D&jsonpathexpression=%24.phoneNumbers%5B%3F%28%40.type%3D%3D%22iPhone%22%29%5D.type&jsontemplate=1&implementation=fc0.5.0#)

Comment: Jsonpath expression is correct. Use https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ to test.